# How to write rspec for blank field? [Rails3.1]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I use rails 3.1 + rspec and factory girl.

My validation of required field (validates_presence_of) is working.
How do I get the test to use that fact as a 'success' rather than a 'failure'
The spec is:

```
describe "Add an industry with no name" do
  context "Unable to create a record when the name is blank" do
    subject do
      ind = Factory.create(:industry_name_blank)
    end
    it { should be_invalid }
  end
end
```

but I get a failure:

```
Failures:

  1) Add an industry with no name Unable to create a record when the name is blank 
     Failure/Error: ind = Factory.create(:industry_name_blank)
     ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid:
       Validation failed: Name can't be blank
     # ./spec/models/industry_spec.rb:45:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
     # ./spec/models/industry_spec.rb:47:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 0.20855 seconds
8 examples, 1 failure
```

Model Code:

```
class Industry < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates_presence_of :name
  validates_uniqueness_of :name
end
```

Factory Code:

```
Factory.define :industry_name_blank, :class => 'industry' do |industry|
  industry.name   { nil }
end
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here's an example... subject gets populated with "Industry.new" by convention

```
describe Industry do

  it "should have an error on name when blank" do
    subject.name.should be_blank
    subject.valid?
    subject.should have(1).error_on(:name)
    #subject.errors.on(:name).should == "is required"
  end

end
```

The last is a little more brittle, but you could do it

More on the syntax: http://cheat.errtheblog.com/s/rspec/

Comment: +1 for the blog link... I've been looking for something like that

Comment: Nope, - Failures:

`  1) Add an industry with no name should have an error on name when blank
     Failure/Error: subject.name.should be_blank
     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `name' for "Add an industry with no name":String
     # ./spec/models/industry_spec.rb:44:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 0.19527 seconds
8 examples, 1 failure`

Comment: as you can see free the factory though `name` attribute does exist

Comment: though I too will +1 for the bloglink !

Comment: I tried:  describe "Add a blank industry " do
  before(:each) do
    @industry = Factory(:industry_name_blank)
  end

  it "should have an error on name when blank" do
    @industry.should_not be_valid
    @industry.name.valid?
    @industry.should have(1).error_on(:name)
    #@industry.errors.on(:name).should == "is required"
  end

end
  but I get `Failures:

  1) Add an industry with no name should have an error on name when blank
     Failure/Error: @industry = Factory(:industry_name_blank)
     ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid:
       Validation failed: Name can't be blank
`

Comment: @MichaelDurrant undefined method of name? typically that means you have not run rake db:test:prepare if name is a column in the db.

Comment: @MichaelDurrant Also be positive that the describe block is exactly how I wrote it, not what you wrote.

Comment: Yes that worked and I have accepted it :) I guess the Describe Industry (i.e. Model Name) is pretty crucial (along with the usual rails magic by convention).  If you could also look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7714998/rails-rspec-when-to-nest-tests-and-what-format-style-should-i-write-the-tests-i I would really appreciate it!

Answer (score 2):

`Factory.build(:industry_name_blank)` generates the object while `Factory.create(:industry_name_blank)` generates *and saves* the created object. In your case it can't save the object, because it is invalid due to lacking `name`, which is why you get the validation error.

So instead of using `create` use `build` to avoid hitting the validation errors: `Factory.build(:industry_name_blank)`. Then you should be able to spec it out like Jesse suggests:

```
subject.should_not be_valid
subject.should have(1).error_on(:name)
```

Comment: Hey that's a great explanation of those two. +1  Thanks Jakob :)

Comment: I edited up your answer a bit.  Please check that it still reads ok for you.